# how to boot without power button

Tags: laptop, boot, bypass

How can I start up my computer without using a power button? I think I have a broken power button (not completely sure, but pretty sure) and I want to know how to make it start up without using a power button. It is an ultrabook, and therefore it is not easy to take apart, attach wires to certain places in the motherboard, etc without special tools. I have already tried using a USB keyboard with a special "power" button on it, but it didn't work. I do not have a PS/2 keyboard with that function. Are there any other ways to do it? I have a warranty and could get it fixed, but I would rather get it working otherwise as it is more convenient than sending it in. Also, it is Lenovo Thinkpad Twist and I cannot remove the power button.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is ['wake on LAN'](http://lifehacker.com/348197/access-your-computer-anytime-and-save-energy-with-wake+on+lan), but even if your laptop has that capability, I think you'd have to turn the machine on to enable it.

Comment: @ForeverWintr sorry, my computer is not configured for that to work

Comment: Got a warranty? Send that sucker in before it expires and you're stuck with a broken power button for life!

Comment: @Iszi turns out the problem wasn't a broken power button; it was actually a very, very weird software issue that stopped the battery from charging. It eventually started up, and then I got rid of the software

Comment: Check YouTube for some videos ... Also check Instructable .

Comment: already done. And , as I said, this issue is already resolved

Answer (score 3):

### Turning on through a docking connector

Some ultrabooks have a docking connector and some of them allow to turn the computer on using a button on a docking station (i.e. through the docking connector). Example of such an ultrabook is Lenovo ThinkPad T440s.

If this is your case you can either use a docking station to turn the computer on or you can try to dismount the docking connector from a broken docking station to connect just the power button.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried the same with T430s and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have identified all available options and have tried the convenient ones (didn't know there were keyboards with boot buttons seems odd). I can't see any solution other than taking it apart and bridging the pins / doing what ever is necessary. You may want to check your manual. It may have some tips. These aren't long term solutions however and sending it is seems much better considering you don't want to go through the hassle every time you want to start your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact specs of your computer you *MAY* be able to switch it on through an Ethernet cable using Wake-On-Lan functionality triggered from another computer or device on the same LAN.   ) I wish my HP Folio had that feature !   Other then that or opening the drive you probably can't.  I doubt a power button on a keyboard would work for you - I suspect its only designed to work from certain partial sleep states - If the computer is powered down, there is no power to the USB port or monitoring it, so no ability to receive the trigger.

A few machines have an "alternative" power button to boot directly into a special setup mode.  You might be able to get some traction if you have one of these buttons.  You should advise if thats the case.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if my machine supports wake from LAN, and even if it does I never set it up. It doesn't have an alternate power button either.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your laptop.. but my Acer has a couple of hotkeys on the keyboard like one to go direct to Email and one direct to the Web both have the effect of turning on the laptop..

Sounds a bit basic but have you tried pressing all the hot keys etc..

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no other way left other than sending it to the service center. A workaround will be putting your laptop to sleep rather than shutdown, I think you will get options for putting the machine to sleep during closing the lid from advanced power option assuming your OS is windows

Comment: Great idea... until the laptop runs out of power and shuts down completely one day.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to start my ThinkPad X220, having the keyboard broken, by removing battery, AC, and BIOS battery. After that, i just plug in the AC power and it starts. Bios battery is located under the touch-pad. You can use an external USB keyboard after that.